# Why can't my Facebook friend and I invite each other to secret groups?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, friends

I made friends with someone for the purpose of her inviting me to join a secret group. She is trying to invite me using the app, but when she clicks "invite" and starts typing my name, it will not populate in the list of suggested friends. I am having the same issue when trying to invite her to a secret group. Why? Do you need to be friends with someone for a certain amount of time before you can invite them to a secret group?

Answer (score -1):

Don’t know if this will work but you can try. If your friends. Get the other person to copy the link address and messenger it over to you. It might work